# Nested Styles in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, styles

I would like to nest `Style`s in WPF.

I have a resource dictionary:

```
<Style x:Key="BottomButtonBar" TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,2" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="90" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,0"/>
    </Style>
</Style>
```

What I want is: If I apply the style "BottomButtonBar" on a grid, Buttons which are inside this grid have `Margin` and `Width` I've defined and the same for the TextBlock inside this grid.

How to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by *imbricate*? That's normally used in the fields of botany and zoology, so makes little sense here.

Comment: I would mean "nested" sorry for the translation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the following solution:

```
<Style x:Key="BottomButtonBar" TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
    <Style.Resources>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,2" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="90" />
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,0"/>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

And in the XAML:

```
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Style="{DynamicResource BottomButtonBar}">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add styles to elements in the Grid, you can make the styles implicit and add them to the resources of the Grid to limit their scope:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
      <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,2" />
      <Setter Property="Width" Value="90" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
      <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
      <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
      <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,0"/>
    </Style>
  <Grid.Resources />

  <Button ... />
</Grid>
```

Comment: The problem is : I can't apply this style in different window cause "Grid.ressources" is not defined in the RessourceDictonary

Comment: Ah ok. I see what you want now. That's quite a cool request. Shooting from the hip I would go down the root of a little attached behaviour if I were you and specify a resource dictionary URI in it and attach it to the grid (or any FrameworkElement). Then in the behaviour resolve the dictionary and merge it into the resources of the control.

Comment: could you, please, add a little example (I can't see what you mean) :)